# Receiving data from Windows Service and show them to MVC

Tags: windows, http, model-view-controller, service

i am new to MVC and i would like some advises to solve my problem.

*The situation*:
i have a windows service that returns a list. Also this windows service opens an http connection to share the results.

I want to show the list in a MVC application. I am connected to Windows Service via MVC "hitting" the IP and the Port of the server, where the Service is installed.

*The Problem*
When i run the MVC application the count of the list is 0.
When i put a breakpoint inside the code of MVC where i get the results of service, the count of the list is correct.

I tried to put task delay because i assumed that the MVC needs some time for the http connection but nothing happened.

*Two questions plz.*

1. Do you think the problem is that the MVC does not have enough time for response or is it something else?
2. Is it a good tactic to share the data from a windows service or i need to create a web service?

tnx in advance

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with showing my service's list of data on MVC. I solved it by adding a [selfHosted web API](https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/hosting-aspnet-web-api/use-owin-to-self-host-web-api) in my service. I created an API Controller that returned the list data in JSON format. My code looked something like this:

```
public class ListController : ApiController
{
    // GET api/list
    public List<Object> Get()
    {
        return (myList);
    }
}
```

Then I [called the API from MVC](https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client) Controller asynchronously :

```
// Create an HttpClient instance
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
// add your url 
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:8080/");
//GET the response async from List Controller
HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("api/list").Result;
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
  var JsonList =response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
  return View(JsonList);
}
```

Finally I will suggest to add Authorization to your API and also use SSL in order to prevent exposing your API data to others.